# Automatically Log-Out Users When They Close Their Browser

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, session

I'm using PHP as server side language and Flex as Front end. In my application there are different levels of users. According to operator's online status QC assigns some job online. I just want to update user's online/offline status when he closes the browser automatically. Flex calling PHP service but its not getting any response. DB(MySQL) is not getting updated. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: How often does it need to update?  Would every few minutes be enough, or does it need to be live?

Comment: Hi @Mikecito, when a user logs in, his online status becomes '1' until he logs out. If he closes the browser directly, I want to make his online status to '0' in DB. I just want to update his online status. I am not setting any session time.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know this is not possible. Your best bet is to save the `datetime` in the database   for the user when the they log on and then run an AJAX script to update that user's time each minute in the database. Then you can check to see if the user has a `datetime` older than a minute to see if the user is logged in. You can adjust the "resolution" of this approach... checking every 5 minutes for example.

Comment: Hi @cbh, Can you please explain me it in detail or can I get any links or samples for this problem.

Comment: @Naveen kumar Pavuturi - You'll have to be more clear with your issue. My response was for the question's title. Your description of the issue seems to point at a communication problem between Flex and PHP (or PHP and the DB). Please further explain the problem you are having by editing the questions's description... including any errors and code snippets in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a service call made before the browser closes, I think you will need to have Javascript send a message to your flex/flash client, then have flex make the service call to let your server know the client/browser is closing.  Once the service call (request/post) succeeds, flash client responds to Javascript to continue browser close.  Caveat here is that I don't think you can consistently have javascript block from browser to browser.  The browser may close before flash can get the service call initiated.  Good luck.

BTW, you can register a call back listener using ExternalInterface and have javascript signal Flex using the javascript function referenced in the callback listener.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I was confused about AJAX but finally its done. I'm calling a function while closing browser. `<body onunload='Logout();'>`. Here's the function

`var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
url = "http://*****.com/public/LogOutThruJS.php?UserID="+UserID+"&LogHistoryId="+LogHistoryId;
function Logout()
{
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url,false); 
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    xmlhttp=null;
    delete xmlhttp;

}`
I hope its understable :).